# Selenium-webdriver (Java Script) wait for element to disappear

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

```
driver.wait(until.elementIsPresent(By.css(".popup-backdrop fade")), 15000);
```

How do I do the opposite of this? I want to wait till the ".popup-backdrop fade" overlay disappears before I click on an element.

I am using Selenium-webdriver (using Javascript and not using Java or Python or C#)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't found the negative wait in the code source. A solution would be to implement your own condition:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var until = webdriver.until;
var By = webdriver.By;

until.elementIsNotPresent = function elementIsNotPresent(locator) {
  return new until.Condition('for no element to be located ' + locator, function(driver) {
    return driver.findElements(locator).then(function(elements) {
      return elements.length == 0;
    });
  });
};

driver.wait(until.elementIsNotPresent(By.css(".popup-backdrop fade")), 15000);
```

Comment: As of selenium 4, `until.Condition` is not a constructor.

Answer (score 5):

As indicated on the comment to the accepted question, until.Condition is not a valid constructor in Selenium 4. Instead, one can do this:

```
const { By, until, Condition } = require('selenium-webdriver');

until.elementIsNotPresent = function elementIsNotPresent(locator) {
  return new Condition('for no element to be located ' + locator, function(driver) {
    return driver.findElements(locator).then(function(elements) {
      return elements.length === 0;
    });
  });
};
```

The reference to using Condition can be found here:
https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/2755

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution of the problem, more inline (but it works, as opposed to the accepted answer which crashes with "TypeError: until.Condition is not a constructor"):

```
    await this._webDriver.wait(() => {
        return this._webDriver.findElements(By.id('loadingIndicator')).then(function(found) {
            return found.length === 0;
        });
    }, 3000, 'The element should disappear');
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also try something like:

```
let faderElement = webdriver.By.css('.fader');
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(faderElement));
let faderElementFound = driver.findElement(faderElement);
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsVisible(faderElementFound));
driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementIsNotVisible(faderElementFound));
```

Comment: Please explain how this code does what OP is asking for

Comment: the code is somehow self explanatory, but: the first 4 lines make sure that the fader is found and visible. Many times the fader is not immediately visible or identifiable, this is why the waiting for the element to be located and then to be visible. And only then with the 5th line we wait for the element to fade out or disappear. If let's say the fader did hide a button, now that button is available to click on it.

Answer (score -2):

## Good news, it's built in now

It looks like `elementIsNotVisible` has been added to `until` after the previous answers were given. I'm using selenium webdriver `4.0.0-beta.3`

Check it out:

```
const timeout = 60 * 1000; // 60 seconds
const element = await driver.findElement(By.id(elementId));

// this is the important line 
await driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(element), timeout);
```